# Pandas Series - force dtype in Series constructor

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have this very simple series.

```
pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), dtype=np.int32)
```

I want to force a dtype, but pandas will overrule my initial setup:

```
Out[6]: 
0    0.764638
1   -1.451616
2   -0.318875
3   -1.882215
4    1.995595
5   -0.497508
6   -1.004066
7   -1.641371
8   -1.271198
9    0.907795
dtype: float64
```

I know I could do this:

`pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), dtype=np.int32).astype("int32")`

But my question is: Why does pandas not handle the data how I want it in the Series constructor? There is no `force` parameter or something like that.

Can somebody explain me what happens there and how I can force the dtype in the series constructor or at least get a warning if the output differs from what I wanted initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
>>> pd.Series(np.random.randn(10).astype(np.int32))
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6   -1
7    0
8    0
9    0
dtype: int32
```

Pandas infers data type correctly. You can force your datatype with one exception. If your data is `float` and you want to force dtype to `intX`, this will not work because pandas does not take the responsibility to loose information and truncate the result.
That is why you have this behaviour.

```
>>> np.random.randn(10).dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> pd.Series(np.random.randn(10)).dtype
dtype('float64')  # OK

>>> pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), dtype=np.int32).dtype
dtype('float64')  # KO -> Pandas does not truncate the data

>>> np.random.randint(1, 10, 10).dtype
dtype('int64')

>>> pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)).dtype
dtype('int64')  # OK

>>> pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 10, 10), dtype=np.float64).dtype
dtype('float64')  # OK -> float64 is a super set of int64
```

Comment: yes I know, my code below gives me the same result. This is in the documentation: `Data type for the output Series. If not specified, this will be inferred from data. .` 
I did specify it, but it was still inferred from the data :/

Comment: Take a closer look at my code: `astype` is applied to ndarray not as parameter of `pd.Series`.